# Example of a set $S$ that is countable, but the set of limit points is uncountable

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What would be an example of a set $S$ so that $S$ is countable. However $S'$ is uncountable. In this $S'$ is the set of all the limit points of $S$.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: What is the biggest countable set (of real numbers) you know of? Why not try that one and see if it works?

Comment: @bof there is no "biggest" countable subset of the reals :)

Comment: @user251257: Nothing like taking a rational approach to the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rationals! In fact on a more general note, if $R$ is some uncountable compact subset, and is of a metric space then, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, there is a finite subset $S_n$ of $R$ such that every element of $R$ is within $n^{-1}$ of an element of $S_n$. Then
$$S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}S_n$$
which is a countable subset of $R$ whose closure is $R$.

Comment: I think this is an explicit example of your general statement: $\{\sin(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is clearly a countable set, but its set of limit points is $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the set of all rationals $$\mathbb Q$$